# Integrating IDLE into Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

Is there any way to integrate IDLE into a Tkinter program as a widget? I have searched google for quite a while and have not come up with anything. Even a point in the right direction would be great. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: not idle per say but if you are refering to a terminal that lets you interact with your windows then you may want to check out http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/262029/tkinter-interactive-terminal-as-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it, but you have the python idlelib library (in PythonXX/Lib/idlelib). Documentation is scarce but I found some people using classes from there. Main idle module in the library I think is pyshell (idle.py calls pyshell). You could start from there...

If as indicated in a comment you want to embed an interpreter shell into a tkinter program and you dont require the shell to be idle, you could embed an IPython shell. IPython gives you very nice tools. There is at least a tkinter application that embeds ipython. Here you have [the code](http://wiki.ipython.org/Old_Embedding/Tkinter).

**Update:**
The above link to the ipython wiki is currently broken.
You can find the code in josePhoenix github repository (see comment below)

Comment: If anyone chances across this and finds the link above broken, I pulled the code out of the Internet Archive and posted it as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/josePhoenix/9938992